# Replace part of text in regex with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to change my URL with regex. For example, my url would looklike this:

`http://domain.com/blog/?page=2&order=asc&by=date`

And with javascript I want to dynamicaly change `order=asc` to `order=desc`. But this function would also work for any of the attribute, such as `by`, so chaging only `order` is not the way.

This is the function:

```
function replace(url, attribute, value) {
    var pattern = new RegExp('([\?|\&])' + attribute + '=.\w+');
    var replacement = '$1' + attribute + '=' + value;
    return url.replace(pattern, '', url);
}
```

So in example, calling function with these variables:

```
url = 'http://domain.com/blog/?page=2&order=asc&by=date'
attribute = 'order'
value = 'desc'
```

Would return `http://domain.com/blog/?page=2&order=desc&by=date`.

Comment: Why not just parse the URL and build a new one?

Comment: Just `url.replace('=asc', '=desc')` is enough

Comment: Not it's not. This is jsut example. It doesn't apply just for `asc/desc`, there can be any string or number.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 maybe, but will it be effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the parameters using an inverse of the jQuery `$.param` function.

```js
(function($) {
  $.unparam = function(value) {
    var params = {};
    var pieces = value.split('&');
    var pair, i, l;
    for (i = 0, l = pieces.length; i < l; i++) {
      pair = pieces[i].split('=', 2);
      params[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = (pair.length == 2 ?
        decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : true);
    }
    return params;
  };
}(jQuery));

var url = 'http://domain.com/blog/?page=2&order=asc&by=date';

$('<p>').text('Before: ' + url).appendTo('body');

var parts = url.split('?');
var base = parts[0];
var params = parts[1];
var data = $.unparam(params);

data.order = 'desc';

var newUrl = base + '?' + $.param(data);

$('<p>').text('After: ' + newUrl).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

## Dynamic Example

```js
(function($) {
  $.unparam = function(value) {
    var params = {};
    var pieces = value.split('&');
    for (var i = 0, l = pieces.length; i < l; i++) {
      var pair = pieces[i].split('=', 2);
      params[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = (pair.length == 2 ?
        decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : true);
    }
    return params;
  };
}(jQuery));

function updateParams(url, data) {
  var parts = url.split('?');
  var base = parts[0];
  var params = parts.length > 0 ? parts[1] : '';
  return base + '?' + $.param($.extend($.unparam(params), data));
}

var oldUrl = 'http://domain.com/blog/?page=2&order=asc&by=date';
var newUrl = updateParams(oldUrl, {
  order: 'desc'
});

$('<p>').text(newUrl).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[I got your example working properly by changing your regex](https://jsfiddle.net/pf7mku4b/2/):

```
new RegExp('([\?|\&])' + attribute + '=.\w+');
```

to this:

```
new RegExp('([?&])' + attribute + '=\\w+');
```

the once-escaped `\w+` is the problem since javascript string interpolation is actually interpreting the backslash itself, and ends up stripping it off and passing regex just a "w". escape this twice:  `\\w+`

also:

the `[\?|\&]` is a character class and doesn't need the `|` alternation (you're actually matching the pipe symbol right now), and quantifiers like `?` that are special chars usually are *not* special inside a character class, so no need to escape them.

you don't need the `.` before the `\w+`, the `\w+` is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for information. I will use it in the future.